# Need help to show a div content inside a contact form field (javascript only)

Tags: javascript

I hope you’re okay!

I have a problem that I can’t solve, but being very little experienced in Javascript I try to be optimistic thinking that my problem may not be so complicated... or maybe yes  ?

for my project, I have several divs used to display a number (different in each div).

When one div is displayed, the others are hidden.

I would need to display the number of the div displayed in a contact form field.

Maybe with a formula like this?

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">349</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:block;">142</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">47</div>

INSIDE MY FORM:
<input type="text" value="If DIV2 display block, show Content(142 in this example)" readonly />
```

would anyone know if this is possible , and if so, can the number displayed in the contact form field be updated if another div is displayed (without needing to refresh the page)

Thank you in advance for your time & ideas !

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do:

```
<div id="div1" class="box hidden" onclick="setValue()">349</div>
<div id="div2" class="box" onclick="setValue()">142</div>
<input type="text" >
```

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```
function setValue() {
  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
  [...boxes].forEach(box => {
    box.classList.toggle("hidden");
    if (!box.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      document.querySelector("input").value = box.innerText;    
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response ! 
Unfortunately I can’t make it work, could you show me in a snippet?